# What is the data type of ID? long?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

ID of the entity which is generated automatically when you create an entity.
What is the data type of it?
I want to know the maximum actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type for the ID is **long**, the MAX value for this type is **2147483647**.

Comment: thank you. so...we can create 2147483647 entities at a maximum for a kind?

Comment: I guess you are correct. If this isnt enough  for you, maybe you can try to create a Name Key.